# How to reset EC2 ubuntu instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

My client created a ubuntu server 16.04 to deploy a web app. And I have been getting difficulties the get the app deployed properly ...

So is there a way for me to reset the server back to its original state via command line?

Comment: What is the "original" state you are referring to?

Comment: Before installing any app. You know when you first hit ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS doesn't have a feature like VmWare's `restore snapshot`. If you want the machine restore to its original state, you have to launch the machine again. But it will get a different IP. There is no way to `reset` your instance to its original state.

**Update:**
Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67300960/3633267) as Amazon recently added this feature in 2021. [Check this Amazon link](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/04/ec2-enables-replacing-root-volumes-for-quick-restoration-and-troubleshooting/)

Comment: even removing all what is been installed once get access?

Comment: Even if you uninstall, it is still not a `original` instance. You never know if uninstall did a good job. There is no guarantee the dependencies are uninstalled correctly.

Answer (score 26):

1. Go to the EC2 Dashboard -> Instances
2. Select the instance you want to reset.
3. Hit the dropdown menu for "Actions" -> "Monitor and troubleshoot" -> "Replace root volume"

[image]

Comment: No , that doesnt work in fact. You need BEFOREHAND at least one (1) Snapshot , like @drsromero suggested.

Comment: @avia No, you can provide a snapshot ID to restore to, but it's NOT mandatory. You can leave the box empty, as the line about it says "Specify a snapshot to restore the root volume to that state. Or **omit the snapshot to restore the root volume to its initial launch state.**"

Comment: "Monitor and troubleshoot" doesn't exist as an option under actions

Comment: @skrhee I added a picture for you

Comment: Note: this requires the instance to be running AFAIK

Comment: Worked for me. One note: if you're in a windows OS using the terminal to ssh,(with public key file) when you finish the process, it may not let you ssh right away and give you this error message: ` WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`. In this case, find your C:\Users\USER\.ssh\known_hosts file, edit and delete the line with the server IP so it will generate a new fingerprint next time you ssh (due to the AWS instance ID that might have changed).

Answer (score 1):

Did you created a snapshot before deploying the app? If not you need to redeploy the AMI in a new EC2 instance.

Comment: I just the orignal state of the ubuntu instance before even installing any app, you know when you first issue "ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xx"

Comment: you can't do it without a snapshot. I recommend you using a third party software for EC2 backups I use Nakivo B&R because I can restore single files or complete instances. There is a free version for 3 ec2, here you have some tutorials here I wrote https://www.dbigcloud.com/backups/245-backups-de-instancias-ec2-con-nakivo-b-r-en-aws-parte-1.html